# Adding vertical divider to material-ui AppBar component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

How can we set vertical divider to AppBar like [muicss's Left/Right divider component](https://www.muicss.com/docs/v1/react/dividers)?

Simply inserting div element with `height: 100%` does not work.

```html
<AppBar position="static" color="default">
  <Toolbar>
    <Typography type="title" color="inherit">
      Title
    </Typography>
    <div style={{
      border: 'solid #ff0000',
      height: '100%'
      }}>
    </div>
    <Typography type="title" color="inherit">
      Title 2
    </Typography> 
  </Toolbar>
</AppBar>
```

Here is the live example code.
https://codesandbox.io/s/54070o6v2x

Thank you.

#### My environment

```
| Tech         | Version |
|--------------|---------|
| Material-UI  | next    |
| React        | 16.2.0  |
| Browser      | Chrome 63.0.3239.84 |
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a right border in order to add a vertical divider.
Use **em** for the border size and padding size so that your elements are responsive. 
You can see the result [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-thompson-w7qe2?file=/demo.js)

```html
<Toolbar>
  <Typography
    type="title"
    color="inherit"
    style={{ borderRight: '0.1em solid black', padding: '0.5em' }}
  >
    Title
  </Typography>

  <Typography type="title" color="inherit" style={{ padding: '0.5em' }}>
    Title 2
  </Typography>
</Toolbar>
```

Answer (score 19):

This can also be used for vertical menubar dividers:

```
<Divider orientation="vertical" flexItem />
```

See here: https://material-ui.com/components/dividers/

Comment: How to increase the spacing between the divider and a menu item?

Comment: Correct answer but in my case it needed to add `sx={{display: "inline"}}`