# Vertical Divider on Material UI Appbar

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to add a vertical Divider component within my Appbar in material-ui. I'm experiencing the same issue found here, however the posted solution does not work for my situation: [Adding vertical divider to material-ui AppBar component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48247562/adding-vertical-divider-to-material-ui-appbar-component)

Take this code:

```
<AppBar position="static" color="default">
  <Toolbar>
    <Typography type="title" color="inherit">
      Title
    </Typography>
    <Divider style={{
      height: '100%'
      }} orientation="vertical">
    </Divider>
    <Typography type="title" color="inherit">
      Title 2
    </Typography> 
  </Toolbar>
</AppBar>
```

The problem is that the divider has a height of 0, despite it being set to 100% in css. The solution posted in the linked question does not work for me because the border does not span the entire height of the AppBar.

For reference, the accepted solution to that question is adding a border to your components within the AppBar:

```
<Toolbar>
  <Typography
    type="title"
    color="inherit"
    style={{ borderRight: '0.1em solid black', padding: '0.5em' }}
  >
    Title
  </Typography>

  <Typography type="title" color="inherit" style={{ padding: '0.5em' }}>
    Title 2
  </Typography>
</Toolbar>
```

Like I said though, this doesn't extend the full height of the AppBar, and to make it look right I need to set the padding to some arbitrary number: 0.764em

It would be nice if I could do this without defining arbitrary values like that. Anyone have any ideas?
Edit: added vertical orientation (this didn't change anything)

Edit 2: Adding sandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-9xz9i?file=/src/demo.js

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to set a fixed height for your `Toolbar` as what @Boussadjra suggested, another possible solution is to not use `height: 100%` on your `Divider` but use `min-height: inherit` instead.

```js
...
<Divider
  orientation="vertical"
  style={{ minHeight: "inherit", color: "red", width: "25px" }}
/>
```

Note that `Toolbar` has `media queries`, and setting a fixed height on it is probably not ideal.

[image: media query for toolbar]

[image: Edit Material demo (forked)]

Answer (score 0):

We can able to style in the following way

```
                       <Divider orientation='vertical' flexItem
                            style={{
                                alignSelf: 'auto',
                                backgroundColor: '#06b554',
                                height: '25px',
                                margin: '0px 36px',
                                width: '1px'
                            }}
                        />
```